# Glue job is deleting columns when creating multiple partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

My Glue job reads a table (an S3 csv file) and then partition it and writes 10 Json files on S3.

I noticed that for some lines in the resulted files, some columns are gone!

This is the line:

```
etalab_named_postgre_csv = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "tab", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
applymapping_etalab_named_postgre_csv= ApplyMapping.apply(frame = etalab_named_postgre_csv, mappings = [("compldistrib", "string", "compldistrib", "string"), ("numvoie", "long", "numvoie", "long"),....], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
path_s3 = "s3://Bucket"
etalab_named_postgre_csv = applymapping_etalab_named_postgre_csv.toDF()
etalab_named_postgre_csv.repartition(10).write.format("json").option("sep",",").option("header", "true").option("mode","Overwrite").save(path_s3)
```

On the output files some of the columns just disappears!

I used Spark on EMR to load the same input table to check the existence of the columns that disappeared.

Is this a common Glue behaviour? How can I prevent that please?

**EDIT:**

I am now sure of the problem.

It seems that the Glue mapping is the source of the problem. When I do

```
applymapping_etalab_named_postgre_csv= ApplyMapping.apply(frame = etalab_named_postgre_csv, mappings = [("compldistrib", "string", "compldistrib", "string"), ("numvoie", "long", "numvoie", "long"),....], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

I declare that compldistrib is a String and I want it as a String in output. If a row contains a numeric value in compldistrib, the mapping will just ignore it!

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of searching I didn't find a solution. The alternative i found is replacing the Glue job with a Spark job using EMR. It is also a lot quicker.

I hope this will help someone.